# Validate xtext editor content which is generated by Grammar file

Tags: java, eclipse, dsl, xtext, xtend

This I know

Suppose we have to validate we have to write `@check` method inside `".xtend"` get data from model then we can validate.

But content which we printed from grammar how can we validate that

consider following grammar

```
IniDCommand: 
    {IniDCommand}
    '@D'(value=ANSS1TERM)?
;IniDCommand: 
    {IniDCommand}
    '@D'(value=ANSS1TERM)?
;
```

In above grammar I can validate `"(value=ANSS1TERM)"` this part  in xtend this data is available in model. But how to validate `'@D'` this data is not available in Model this we are printing from grammar.

> How we can read or validate content inside xtend which we printed on Xtext Editor from
>    grammar(.xtext) file.

For more clarity i am adding following example

considere following example

```
IniC0_61: 
    {IniC0_61}
    '@C0,61,'
    ;
```

in Editor i can see like this

```
@C0,61
```

Now someone type or change above line in editor like this

```
@@C0,61
```

> In above line user added extra "@" rest i am printing from grammar.
>   This should throw an error by saying "@@" not allowed.

This how my part of grammar(.xtext) look like

```
grammar com.herzog.pmide.RoutingLineINI with org.eclipse.xtext.common.Terminals 

import "platform:/resource/com.herzog.pmide.routingline.xtext.model/model/pmrouting.ecore" 
import "http://www.eclipse.org/emf/2002/Ecore" as ecore

IniRoutingLineProject:
    {IniRoutingLineProject}
        (iniRoutingConfig=IniRoutingConfiguration)?
    ;

IniRoutingConfiguration:    
    {IniRoutingConfiguration}
    (iniRoutingSectConfig=IniRoutingLogicSection)

;

IniRoutingLogicSection:
    {IniRoutingLogicSection}
    '[Routing]'('\r\n')*
    (routingLines+=IniRoutingLine)*('\r\n')*
;

terminal ALPHA :('a'..'z'|'A'..'Z');

terminal NUM:('0'..'9')+;

terminal SYMBOL : ('.'|','|'('|')'|'{'|'}'|'<'|'>'|'+'|'-'|'*'|'%'|'!'|'"'|':'|'|'|'?'|'#'|'_'|' '|'=');

terminal SYMBOL1 : ('['|']')*;

terminal SYMBOL2 : ('/'|';')* ;

terminal ANS : (ALPHA|NUM|SYMBOL)* SYMBOL2;

terminal SL_COMMENT : '//-' !('\n'|'\r')* ('\r'? '\n')?;

terminal ML_COMMENT : '//*' -> '*//';

ANSTERM : ANS;

ANSS1TERM : (ANS|SYMBOL1)+;

GRPCOMMENT_STR_END : SYMBOL2("===========================================================================================================================================================================") ;

GRPCOMMENT : 
    (GRPCOMMENT_STR_END)('\r\n')*
    SYMBOL2(ANSS1TERM)('\r\n')*
    (GRPCOMMENT_STR_END)('\r\n')*
;

IniDCommand: 
    {IniDCommand}
    '@D'(value=ANSS1TERM)?
;

LINECOMMENT : 
//  (LINECOMMENT_STR_END)('\r\n')*
//  (ANSS1TERM|LINECOMMENT)('\r\n')*
//  (LINECOMMENT_STR_END)?('\r\n')*;
    (('/*'('\r\n')*
    (ANSS1TERM)('\r\n')*
    (LINECOMMENT)?('\r\n')*
     '*/'?('\r\n')*)|GENCOMMENT)
;

GENCOMMENT : 
    SYMBOL2(ANSS1TERM)('\r\n')*
    (GENCOMMENT)?
;

IniCommand:
    (IniDCommand)
;

IniRoutingLine: 
    (groupComment=GRPCOMMENT)?('\r\n')*
    (comment=LINECOMMENT)?('\r\n')*
    (unitPositionSampleTypeWay=('Warning_Rate='|'Busy_Rate='|'MaxRecursionConcurence='|'WS_Speed='|'ReactivationTime='|'WaitTime_WS_Reuse='|ANSTERM))(commands+=IniCommand)*('\r\n')*
//(unitPositionSampleTypeWay=ANS1TERM)'='(commands+=IniCommand)*('\r\n')*
;
```

Comment: i dont understand this question. can you please rephrase

Comment: i added extra example for more clarity

Comment: Still don’t understand. This (syntax errors)will give an error without implementing any checks

Comment: nope i am not getting that error..thats why i want check that

Comment: Please give a complete minimal grammar and sample model that shows the problem

Comment: i added grammar file @ChristianDietrich

Comment: I. We’d a mininmal but complete grammar

Comment: i added error free grammar @ChristianDietrich

Comment: need a test model for that grammar as well. please note it is highly ambigous. thus i wonder why you dont use this as test grammar and test model: https://gist.github.com/cdietrich/95d786a45d1e611915534de628a64986